# All links in html, css have the same hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

```
ul li a:hover{
    color: black;
}
/* Search Button */
.search_button{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 78px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    height: auto;
}
/* Middle Section */
/* Middle Section Main Picture */
.middle_section_image{
    display: block;
    margin: 1px auto;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 50px;
}
/* quote, explore */
.quote{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    color: whitesmoke;
    bottom: 475px;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.explore{
    width: 80px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0px 30px;
    background-color: black;
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 30px;
    bottom: 475px;
}
```

This is a part of my CSS file. I have many links in my file and I want to add different attributes to them. But if I add one attribute to one link, the same attribute is added to all the links. I want all the links to have individual attributes

Comment: Post your HTML as well.

Comment: So you add a class for that specific link.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways you could go about this.

You could add a css class or id selector for each of the different link types that you want to have:

```css
/* class */
a.home-link { color: #000; }
a.home-link:hover { color: #00f; }
a.contact-link { color: #aaa; }
a.contact-link:hover { color: #0f0; }

/* id */
a#home-link { color: #000; }
a#contact-link { color: #aaa; }
...
```

You could also create css selectors based on known attributes that will be shared by links you want to target.

```css
a[href="home.html"] { color: #000; }
a[href="contact.html"] { color: #000; }
```

[MDN: CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

[MDN: CSS Class Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

[MDN: CSS ID Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

#### Give a specifier to each element.

First, check if you are really styling the `a` tag and not the `li` tag. If that is not the case, try giving a class, id or using `:nth-of-type` css pseudo-element.

It goes like this:

```css
menu{
  ul{
     li{
        a:nth-of-type(example number){
            background-color: red;
         }
       }
    }
}
```

#### Hope this helps.

Comment: Also, include a piece of HTML file, it makes things a lot easier. Note that in the example, I am using SCSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same ul li a for all the links the webpage will read your code as it is for all the links you declared. But just like Dan mulin said. Try using class or selectors inside your html element to give an identity for the elements you want to declare it's properties.